# how to convert a varchar date with zulu time to a timestamp in snowflake

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to convert the next varchar date to timestamp:

```
2022-02-01T02:37:35.792000Z
```

For which I will like to preserve the native format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffZ
```

I´ve tried `try_to_timestamp()` function but snowflake console returns:

> Can't parse *date* as timestamp with format *format*

Do you know how may I convert this class of varchar date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mi` instead of `mm` for minutes:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-02-01T02:37:35.792000Z','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mi:ss.ffffffZ');
```